# equivalent Laravel nullable validation in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

In `Laravel` framework we have `nullable` in validation, it does mean when field is't null the field should be validate and when it's null, validation shouldn't check field, for example:

```php
'name'=>'nullable|min:3|max:20`
```

now i want to know whats equivalent of this validation in `Laravel` can be implemented with `vuelidate` in `vuejs`?

```js
import {required, minLength, maxLength} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            mobile_number: '',
            name: '',
            family: '',
        }
    }, validations: {
        mobile_number: {
            required,
            minLength: minLength(11),
            maxLength: maxLength(11)
        },
        name: {
            minLength: minLength(3),
            maxLength: maxLength(25),
        },
        family: {
            minLength: minLength(3),
            maxLength: maxLength(20)
        }
    }, methods: {
    }, mounted() {
    }
}
```

in this code i get error when `name` or `family` hasn't minimum length after type and delete all character and this error should be gone because i don't define `required` for them

Comment: requiredIf, see docs https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-builtin-validators (example code above the title)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Lawrence Cherone

```js
name: {
    required: requiredIf(function (value) {
        return value >= 3 && value <= 25
    }),
    minLength: minLength(3),
    maxLength: maxLength(25),
},
```